# Como mudar o texto do botão com Ajax?

Tags: ajax

Se trata de um projeto em JavaWeb, mas já estou conseguindo captura o valor vindo do botão quando clica nele.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Toda vez que clica no botão a IDE eclipse consegui imprimir o valor do botão, se clicar nele, ele retorna um **false**, se clicar novamente no botão ele retorna **true**

como mostra abaixo;
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou precisando de um algoritomo que ao clicar no botão ele mostre **pausar** e quando clicar novamente ele mostre **iniciar**

Esse é o HTML

```
<div class="panel-body"  >
                        <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">   
                         <c:if test="${suspenso == false}">
                                <button id="pausar" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" title="Pausar" onclick="pausar();">Pausar</button> 
                         </c:if>
                         <c:if test="${suspenso != false}">
                                <button id="pausar" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" title="Pausar" onclick="pausar();">Iniciar</button> 
                        </c:if>
                        </div>
            </div>
```

Eu tentei isso;

```
function pausar(){

        $(document).on('click', '#pausar', function() {
            $("#status").html("mudando o nome do botão para botao2");
            $(this).attr("id","botao2").html("BOTÃO 2");
        }); 
        $(document).on('click', '#pausar', function() {
            $("#status").html("retornando o nome do botão para botao1");
            $(this).attr("id","botao1").html("BOTÃO 1");
        });
    document.forms[1].action = "AdministracaoRemessa!pausar";
    document.forms[1].submit();
}
```

Era bom que fosse feito em Ajax, porque não precisaria carregar novamente a página.

Comment: Dá uma pesquisada por "ajax" na busca. Tem muito material aqui no site sobre AJAX.

Comment: Isso não precisa ser feito em AJAX, o clique no botão tu pode fazer em JS apenas com a ação de click clicou fica true, clicou fica false e mudar o valor do texto no botão, isso não vai gerar recarregamento de pagina, se é esse o problema.